# A faster method than "for" to scan a DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm finding a way (using a built-in pandas function) to scan a column of a DataFrame comparing its-self values for different indices.

Here an example using a `for cycle`. I've a dataframe with a single column `col 1`. I want to create a column `col 2` with TRUE/FALSE in this way.

```py
df["col_2"] = "False"

N=5
```

```
for idx in range(0,len(df)-N):

    for i in range (idx+1,idx+N+1):

          if(df["col_1"].iloc[idx]==df["col_1"].iloc[i]):

                df["col_2"].iloc[idx]=True
```

What I'm trying to do is to compare the value of `col 1` for the i-th index with the next N indices.

I'd like to do the same operation without using a `for cycle` . I've already tried to use a `shift` and `df.loc` , but the computational time is similar.

Comment: check out `duplicated`.

Comment: hi Lorenzo. Please provide a small input sample and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like

```py
df["col_1_shifted"] = df["col_1"].shift(N)
df["col_2"] = (df["col_1"] == df["col_1_shifted"])
```

Answer (score 0):

**update**: looking more carefully at your double-loop, it seems you want to flag all duplicates except the last. That's done by just changing the `keep` argument to `'last'` instead of the default `'first'`.

As suggested by @QuangHoang in the comments, `duplicated()` works nicely for this:

```py
newdf = df.assign(col_2=df.duplicated(subset='col_1', keep='last'))
```

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, 10), columns=['col_1'])
newdf = df.assign(col_2=df.duplicated(subset='col_1', keep='last'))

>>> newdf
   col_1  col_2
0      2  False
1      0   True
2      1   True
3      0   True
4      0  False
5      3  False
6      1   True
7      1  False
8      4   True
9      4  False
```